# Why does my windowed-sinc function have non-linear phase?

Tags: python, filtering, signal-processing, lowpass-filter

Similar to many tutorials on the web, I've tried implementing a windowed-sinc lowpass filter using the following python functions:

```
def black_wind(w):
''' blackman window of width w'''
    samps = np.arange(w)
    return (0.42  - 0.5 * np.cos(2 * np.pi * samps/ (w-1)) + 0.08 * np.cos(4 * np.pi * samps/ (w-1)))

def lp_win_sinc(tw, fc, n):
''' lowpass sinc impulse response 
Parameters:
    tw = approximate transition width [fraction of nyquist freq]
    fc = cutoff freq [fraction of nyquest freq]
    n = length of output. 
Returns:
    s = impulse response of windowed-sinc filter appended zero-padding
    to make len(s) = n
'''
    m = int(np.ceil( 4./tw / 2) * 2) 
    samps = np.arange(m+1)
    shift = samps - m/2
    shift[m/2] = 1
    h = np.sin(2 * np.pi * fc * shift)/shift
    h[m/2] = 2 * np.pi * fc
    h = h * black_wind(m+1)
    h = h / h.sum()
    s = np.zeros(n)
    s[:len(h)] = h
    return s
```

For input: 'tw = 0.05', 'fc = 0.2', 'n = 6000', the magnitude of the fft seems reasonable.

```
tw = 0.05
fc = 0.2
n = 6000
lp = lp_win_sinc(tw, fc, n)
f_lp = np.fft.rfft(lp)
plt.figure()
x = np.linspace(0, 0.5, len(f_lp))
plt.plot(x, np.abs(f_lp))
```

[magnitude of lowpass filter response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3p7wk.png)

however, the phase is non-linear above ~fc.

```
plt.figure()
x = np.linspace(0, 0.5, len(f_lp))
plt.plot(x, np.unwrap(np.angle(f_lp)))
```

[phase of lowpass filter response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mmEnD.png)

Given the symmetry of the non-zero-padded portion of the impulse response, I would expect the resulting phase to be linear. Can someone explain what is going on? Perhaps I'm using a numpy function incorrectly, or maybe my expectations are incorrect. I'm very grateful for any help.

***********************EDIT***********************

based on some of the helpful comments to this question and some more work, I wrote a function that produces zero phase delay and is therefore a bit easier to interpret the np.angle() results.

```
def lp_win_sinc(tw, fc, n):
    m = int(np.ceil( 2./tw) * 2) 
    samps = np.arange(m+1)
    shift = samps - m/2
    shift[m/2] = 1
    h = np.sin(2 * np.pi * fc * shift)/shift
    h[m/2] = 2 * np.pi * fc
    h = h * np.blackman(m+1)
    h = h / h.sum()
    s = np.zeros(n)
    s[:len(h)] = h
    return np.roll(s, -m/2)
```

The main change here is using np.roll() to place the line of symmetry at t=0.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a better fit for http://dsp.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The magnitudes in the stop band are crossing zero.  The phase of the coefficient after a zero crossing will jump by 180 degrees, which is confusing np.angle()/np.unwrap().   -1*180° = 1*0°

Comment: I want to understand your point about zero crossing. The phase crosses zero many time in the pass band as well and it seems np.unwrap handled them ok, is there something in the stop band in particular that would cause the crossings to be treated differently?

Comment: It's not the phase crossing zero, it's the amplitude/magnitude crossing zero.  This only happens in the stop band, because the amplitude is very large *everywhere* in the pass band.  When the amplitude crosses zero, it "really" goes from positive to negative or vice-versa.  np.angle interprets this as a 180 degree phase jump.  Imagine you had a *zero* phase filter...  Where the response is (0.001+0j), np.angle says 0.  Where the response is (-0.001+0j), np.angle says pi.

Comment: See, for example: https://ccrma.stanford.edu/~jos/fp/Example_Zero_Phase_Filter_Design.html

Answer (score 1):

The phase as shown in your graph is in fact linear. It's a constant slope in the passband, corresponding to a constant delay in the time domain. It's a much steeper slope, which renders as wrapping around at 2pi boundaries, in the stopband. But the value of the phase in the stopband is not particularly important since those frequencies aren't going to come through the filter anyway.

Comment: Thanks!. Motivated by your comment, I was able to look at the phase plot with fresh eyes and see that the slope does appear to be the same in the stop band as it is in the pass band - provided the 2pi jumps are healed. I had naively expected np.unwrap() would take care of this for me, but it seems something isn't working there. If it is the same slope, it's definitely a nice linear phase filter. Thanks again.